# Checking if user exists in MySQL database fails

Tags: c#, mysql

Not sure why the following code gives me an exception. I'm trying to check if a username exists in a MySQL database, if not then I want to create a user. If I run either query by itself then it works ok but not together.

```
    int valid = -1;            

    using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(conString))
        {
            cnn.Open();

            bool usernameExists = false;

            string sql1 = String.Format("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = \"{0}\"", username);
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(sql1, cnn);

            usernameExists = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar() > 0;

            if (!usernameExists)
            {
                string sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password) VALUES(\"{0}\", \"{1}\")", username, password);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cnn);

                valid = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    return valid;
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: fails how, exactly? Do you get an exception?

Comment: The code is on a web service so it's hard to debug. The exception message in Visual Studio is a 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'

Comment: Just a quick note, why use String.Format instead of MySqlParameters? It's way better and prevents SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JoshuaBakker

Comment: @mosdave I provided your code edited with parameters in an answer, let me know please if that fixes the bug.

Comment: doesn't MySQL use single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: @Jules yes, but you don't need quotes when using MySqlParameters, which already is much better. But you're right, it uses `WHERE username = ''` instead of `WHERE username = ""`

Comment: @JoshuaBakker of course! Using parameters will always be better, but I was thinking about the root cause of this problem...

Comment: @Jules oh okay, well your statement is right :)

Comment: @mosdave At which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent duplicate entries to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478342/prevent-duplicate-entries-to-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing the first query from:

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = @username LIMIT 1", cnn);
```

to

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(UserID) FROM Users WHERE Username = @username", cnn);
int valid = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, MySQL uses single quotes. This means your query would be:

```
string.format("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = '{0}' LIMIT 1", Username);
```

However, this is very vulnerable with SQL injection. Here's a code to use MySQL Parameters to prevent it.

```
int valid = -1;            

using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(conString))
    {
        cnn.Open();

        bool usernameExists = false;

        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = @username LIMIT 1", cnn);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

        usernameExists = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar() > 0;

        if (!usernameExists)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password) VALUES(@username, @password)", cnn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

            valid = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
return valid;
```

Could you try this?

Comment: I get the same TargetInvocationException. Whenever I've had this error before it's usually a syntax error in my SQL but as I said before, each query runs ok if I run them separately.

Comment: Do you know which line gives that error? That way maybe I can figure out the error. It's hard to fix an error over multiple lines.