# CheckIfExist. If exist don't insert the data, if not insert the data

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem on how to insert data into two different table. So my requirements is this.

- Under Group Details, The user need to click all the needed information on the dropdown menu and input on the textbox of the table grid view before clicking the ADD Link, after this the page will load displaying the Added Job Title and business group details. The user is allowed to input as many Job title as the user want.

I already finished the table but I have problems in saving the data that I input.

So my first table looks like this [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqJkV.png)

and I edit it and this is my table [Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPDt2.png)

So my problem is this, in my database i have two table. One is `EMPGROUP_TBL` with columns SEQID, masterID, Business Unit, Division, Sub-Division etc. and the other is `EMP_MASTERTBL` with columns MasterID, Name, LastName, Jobtitle.

Now everytime I click Add link the jobtitle will not be able to save in the EMP_MASTERTBL so I create a code in VB.Net that will update the EMP_MASTERTBL table when I click the add button under Group Details.

Here's my codes.

```
If UpdateInsDelRecord("INSERT INTO EMPGROUP_TBL (MASTERID, BUSINESS_UNIT, " & _
                  "DIVISION, SUB_DIVISION, CLASSIFICATION, SUB_CLASSIFICATION) VALUES " & _
                  "('" & HandleQuote(Me.lblval_Empid.Text) & "', " & _
                  "'" & Me.ddl_BusinessUnit.SelectedValue.ToString() & "' ," & _
                  "'" & val_division & "' ," & _
                  "'" & val_subdivision & "' ," & _
                  "'" & Me.ddl_Classification.SelectedValue.ToString() & "' ," & _
                  "'" & Me.ddl_SubClassification.SelectedValue.ToString() & "')" & _
                  ";" & _
                   "UPDATE EMP_MASTERTBL SET JOBTITLE = '" & Me.txtJobtitle.Text & "' " & _
                   "WHERE MASTERID = '" & Me.lblval_Empid.Text & "'") = True Then
    Return True
    Response.Redirect("eHR_EmpMaintenance.aspx")
Else
    Return False
End If
```

But the user must be able to add as many as Jobtitle and EMPGROUP_TBL details as the user want. So I'm thinking that I'll just write another query for that? How can I add the Group Details and be able to add as many as Jobtitle as the user want?

**CheckIfExist**

I figured maybe I could use the CheckIfExist and if the employee has an existing data to the jobtitle, business unit, division, sub-division, classification and sub-classification similar to the one that you will add, the messagebox will show that the data already exist. If no data found then it will be able to add the details under the employee's group details. And if you input similar jobtitle but different business unit etc. the data will just be updated and vice versa.

Here's what my code for this.

```
   Function SaveUserGroup() As Boolean
    Try
        Dim jobtitle As String = Me.txtJobtitle.Text
        Dim businessunit As String = Me.ddl_BusinessUnit.SelectedValue
        Dim division As String = Me.ddl_Division.SelectedValue
        Dim subdivision As String = Me.ddl_SubDivision.SelectedValue
        Dim classification As String = Me.ddl_Classification.SelectedValue
        Dim subclassification As String = Me.ddl_SubClassification.SelectedValue
        Dim CheckMasterTblIfExist As Boolean
        Dim CheckGroupTblIfExist As Boolean
        Dim insrtResult As Boolean
        Dim seqid As String = Me.lblSEQID.Text
        Dim emp_id As String = Request.QueryString("emp_id")

        If jobtitle <> "" And businessunit <> "Please Select" And division <> "Please Select" And subdivision <> "Please Select" And classification <> "Please Select" And subclassification <> "Please Select" Then
            CheckMasterTblIfExist = CheckRecord("SELECT MASTERID, JOBTITLE FROM EMP_MASTERTBL WHERE JOBTITLE = '" & jobtitle & "' AND MASTERID = '" & emp_id & "' ")
            CheckGroupTblIfExist = CheckRecord("SELECT * FROM EMPGROUP_TBL WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = '" & businessunit & "' AND DIVISION = '" & division & "' AND SUB_DIVISION = '" & subdivision & "' AND CLASSIFICATION = '" & classification & "' AND SUB_CLASSIFICATION = '" & subclassification & "' AND MASTERID = '" & emp_id & "' AND SEQID = '" & seqid & "'")
            If Not CheckMasterTblIfExist And CheckGroupTblIfExist Then
                insrtResult = UpdateInsDelRecord("UPDATE EMP_MASTERTBL SET JOBTITLE = '" & jobtitle & "' " & _
                                                 "WHERE MASTERID = '" + Me.lblval_Empid.Text + "'" & _
                                                 ";" & _
                                                 "INSERT INTO EMPGROUP_TBL(MASTERID, BUSINESS_UNIT, " & _
                                                 "DIVISION, SUB_DIVISION, CLASSIFICATION, SUB_CLASSIFICATION) VALUES " & _
                                                 "('" & HandleQuote(Me.lblval_Empid.Text) & "', " & _
                                                 "'" & businessunit & "' ," & _
                                                 "'" & division & "' ," & _
                                                 "'" & subdivision & "' ," & _
                                                 "'" & classification & "' ," & _
                                                 "'" & subclassification & "')")

                If Not insrtResult Then
                    MessageBox("alert('Error Ocurred While Inserting a Data.')")
                Else
                    MessageBox("alert('Successfully Added.')")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox("alert('Data Already Exist.')")
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox("Error Ocurred while Inserting a data")
        Throw
    End Try
End Function
```

I haven't been completed the code yet. I'm in the adding if there's no data and my problem is that the messagebox keeps on telling me that the data already exist even if there's still no employee's group details that added. Please help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent duplicate entries to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478342/prevent-duplicate-entries-to-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
begin tran
if exists (select * from table with (updlock,serializable) where key = @key)
begin
   update table set ...
   where key = @key
end
else
begin
   insert into table (key, ...)
   values (@key, ...)
end
commit tran
```

you can use like this