# Check if Exist or Not then Insert Update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I need to check if the data exist if the data didn't exist then I'll be able to insert and update but if the data exist the messagebox will show that the data already exist but when I tried to add same data that already exist it still add and no messagebox shown that it already exist.

here's my code

```
  If jobtitle <> "" And businessunit <> "Please Select" And division <> "Please Select" And subdivision <> "Please Select" And classification <> "Please Select" And subclassification <> "Please Select" Then
            insrtResult = UpdateInsDelRecord("UPDATE EMP_MASTERTBL SET JOBTITLE = '" & jobtitle & "' " & _
                                   "WHERE MASTERID = '" & empID & "'" & _
                                   ";" & _
                                   "INSERT INTO EMPGROUP_TBL(MASTERID, BUSINESS_UNIT, " & _
                                   "DIVISION, SUB_DIVISION, CLASSIFICATION, SUB_CLASSIFICATION) VALUES " & _
                                   "('" & HandleQuote(empID) & "', " & _
                                   "'" & businessunit & "' ," & _
                                   "'" & division & "' ," & _
                                   "'" & subdivision & "' ," & _
                                   "'" & classification & "' ," & _
                                   "'" & subclassification & "')")

            If Not insrtResult Then
                MessageBox("alert('Error Ocurred While Inserting a Data.')")
            Else
                MessageBox("alert('Successfully Added.')")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox("alert('Data Already Exist.')")
        End If
```

what could be the problem to my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent duplicate entries to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478342/prevent-duplicate-entries-to-database)

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: What does it mean if data exists ? In the DB or in the form? 
In latter case, in your code it will be enough the only one of the fields is valorized, in order to let the insert and update execute

Comment: if the data exists in the DB for just one particular employee. I have an employee with business group details and if I want to add their business unit details it needed to check if she already has the business unit that she wants to add if it exists then the messagebox will show that it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server check the MERGE query, i used this to perform an "upsert" on my own db, it also seems to be performing fast enough.

You can chose a condition and perform different operations whether it returns true or false (e.g. if ID already exists then update, else insert)

For MySql i think there are solutions much more easier to write, wich unfortunatly i can't remember at the moment

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx