# Error while inserting MySQL with ASP.Net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I'm newbie to MySQL, I'm trying to check if the user exists in the database before inserting a record but I'm getting this error 1064,error in your SQL syntax.
MySQL statement

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM tvstream.t_users WHERE fb_id=`123456`)=0 THEN 
Begin 
  INSERT INTO `tvstream`.`t_users` (`fb_id` ,`user_name` ,`email` ,`gender`) 
  Values (`123456`,`Daina`,`Daina@gmail.com`,`Female`) 
End
```

ASP Code

```
        StringBuilder SQL_Add = new StringBuilder("IF (SELECT count(*) FROM tvstream.t_users WHERE fb_id=`" + fb_id +"`)=0 THEN ");
        SQL_Add.Append("Begin ");
        SQL_Add.Append("INSERT INTO  `tvstream`.`t_users` (`fb_id` ,`user_name` ,`email` ,`gender`)");
        SQL_Add.Append(" Values (`" + fb_id + "`,`" + user_name + "`,`" + email + "`,`" + gender + "`)");
        SQL_Add.Append(" End");

        Response.Write(SQL_Add.ToString());
        MySqlConnection m_cnn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

        m_cnn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQL_Add.ToString());
        cmd.Connection = m_cnn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please advice and thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent duplicate entries to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478342/prevent-duplicate-entries-to-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make one sql query for checking the user existance, and another one for inserting a new user.

Checking:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tvstream.t_users WHERE fb_id=`123456`
```

Inserting:

```
  INSERT INTO `tvstream`.`t_users` (`fb_id` ,`user_name` ,`email` ,`gender`) 
  Values (`123456`,`Daina`,`Daina@gmail.com`,`Female`)
```

Basically you should run the first query, check the result, and the execute the insertion.

I you really need to do it completely by SQL-side, then you will need a stored procedure in you DB.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION InsertUnique(fb_id VARCHAR(20), user_name VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(40), gender VARCHAR(10))
  RETURNS INT

  BEGIN
    DECLARE s INT;

    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM tvstream.t_users WHERE fb_id=`123456`)=0 THEN SET s = 1;
    ELSE SET s = 0;
    END IF;

    IF s = 0 THEN 
        INSERT INTO `tvstream`.`t_users` (`fb_id` ,`user_name` ,`email` ,`gender`) 
  Values (fb_id,user_name,email,gender) 
    END IF;

    RETURN s;
  END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I didn't check the syntax, it may need to be fixed.